# Turning off security messages for WPF XBAP applications in Internet Explorer

Tags: wpf, security, internet-explorer, configuration, xbap

I'm developing a WPF XBAP application. When i try to open it in Internet Explorer (9.0.8112.16421 Update version 9.0.9 KB2722913, Windows 7) every time security warning is popped up. Twice.
[image: Security warning]

That's very annoying and acceptable only in developer environment, there is a need to turn them both off. Project configuration is as follows : Security - "Enable ClickOnce security settings" (when its disabled application won't run at all) - "This is a full trust application"; "Signing" - "Sign the ClickOne manifests" (with test certificate which is imported to Trusted Root Certification Authorities). In IE both internet and intranet zones have "WPF browsers applications" set to "Enable" (that may not have effect because *.xbap is loaded from file system). In case I don't have alternative ways to integrate WPF application into browser (Silverlight is not an option, there is a requirement about full .NET framework targeting) i'm looking for solution of above described problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved via manual addition of assembly's certificate (*.pfx) to Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Trusted Publishers as described here : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but hoping for reply. Is there a way to add them to Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Trusted Publishers for all users (automatically)?